# how to export to pdf a graph based on a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe and I am using the useful .plot() method.

The dataframe looks like

```
col1   col2   col3
1      2      3
7      0      3
1      2      2
```

I therefore use `df.plot()` to get the chart I want.

Problem is, I would like to export the chart to a pdf. Ideally, I could also generate other charts (based on this dataframe) and add them to the pdf.

It is possible to do so ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

To output a single figure as a pdf, you can use `plt.savefig('myfile.pdf')`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[7,0,3],[1,2,2]],columns=['col1','col2','col3'])

df.plot()

plt.savefig('myfile.pdf')
```

---

To output multiple images to one pdf, you can use [`PdfPages`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_pdf_api.html#matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages), as shown in the example [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/multipage_pdf.html).

A minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[7,0,3],[1,2,2]],columns=['col1','col2','col3'])

with PdfPages('multipage_pdf.pdf') as pdf:

    df.plot()
    pdf.savefig()
    plt.close()

    df.plot(kind='bar')
    pdf.savefig()
    plt.close()
```

Comment: thank you tom, this solution works great. only problem, I run into  `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'myfile.pdf'` when I try to re-run your code. I closed the file and I have writing rights.. any ideas?

Comment: do you have the pdf file open in another application? Perhaps that's blocking you from overwriting it?

Comment: I dont but I just closed the window that contains the file and it works again. I guess that was the problem

Comment: tom just a follow up question. do you know how can I add some margins to the pdf? as of now, the code copy pastes the chart almost without margins, so that y scales are not well readable.

Comment: Try `plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.3)`

Answer (score 14):

The following should do:

```
plot = df.plot()
plot.get_figure().savefig('output.pdf', format='pdf')
```

It actually depends in whether or not your backend supports pdf output (most do). Check with:

```
'pdf' in plot.get_figure().canvas.get_supported_filetypes()
```

Comment: This answer is a lot simpler than the current accepted answer, and it could be even shorter if you removed the `format='pdf'` from `savefig`. `pandas` infers the format from the file extension, so just `output.pdf` (or `output.png` or `output.svg`) would work as well.

Answer (score 2):

The following code creates a pdf with 2 pages (one plot on each page):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 3, 7], 'col2': [1, 4, 5], 'col3': [2, 7, 1]})

with PdfPages('foo.pdf') as pdf:
   fig=df.plot(x='col1', y='col2').get_figure()
   pdf.savefig(fig)

   fig=df.plot(x='col1', y='col3').get_figure()
   pdf.savefig(fig)
```

You can add as many plots as you want by repeating the last two lines.