# Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway

Tags: python, opencv

I try to use library cv2 for changing picture.
In mode debug I found out that problem in function **cv2.namedWindow**:

```
def run(self):
    name_of_window = 'Test_version'
    image_cv2 = cv2.imread('external_data/probe.jpg')
    cv2.namedWindow(name_of_window, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow(name_of_window, image_cv2)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

After cv2.namedWindow appears warning and program stops.
I will be pleasure if somebody give the advice.

When I call os.environ , appears this:

```
environ({
            'PATH': '/home/spartak/PycharmProjects/python_base/lesson_016/env/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin',
            'LC_MEASUREMENT': 'ru_RU.UTF-8', 'XAUTHORITY': '/run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.MJ52B1',
            'INVOCATION_ID': 'dd129fae7f7c452cb8fa8cd53b9da873', 'XMODIFIERS': '@im=ibus',
            'LC_TELEPHONE': 'ru_RU.UTF-8',
            'XDG_DATA_DIRS': '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop',
            'GDMSESSION': 'ubuntu', 'LC_TIME': 'ru_RU.UTF-8', 'SNAP_COMMON': '/var/snap/pycharm-community/common',
            'SNAP_INSTANCE_KEY': '', 'SNAP_USER_COMMON': '/home/spartak/snap/pycharm-community/common',
            'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS': 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus',
            'IDE_PROJECT_ROOTS': '/home/spartak/PycharmProjects/python_base', 'PS1': '(env) ', 'SNAP_REVISION': '256',
            'XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP': 'ubuntu:GNOME', 'JOURNAL_STREAM': '8:37824', 'LC_PAPER': 'ru_RU.UTF-8',
            'SESSION_MANAGER': 'local/spartak-pc:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2082,unix/spartak-pc:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2082',
            'USERNAME': 'spartak', 'LOGNAME': 'spartak', 'PWD': '/home/spartak/PycharmProjects/python_base/lesson_016',
            'MANAGERPID': '1951', 'IM_CONFIG_PHASE': '1', 'PYCHARM_HOSTED': '1', 'GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS': 'JS ERROR;JS LOG',
            'PYTHONPATH': '/home/spartak/PycharmProjects/python_base:/home/spartak/PycharmProjects/python_base/lesson_012/python_snippets:/home/spartak/PycharmProjects/python_base/chatbot:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/third_party/thriftpy:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev:/home/spartak/.cache/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.2/cythonExtensions:/home/spartak/PycharmProjects/python_base/lesson_016',
            'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'LC_ADDRESS': 'ru_RU.UTF-8',
            'GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE': '/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop',
            'BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT': '/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop',
            'IPYTHONENABLE': 'True', 'GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID': 'this-is-deprecated', 'GTK_MODULES': 'gail:atk-bridge',
            'VIRTUAL_ENV': '/home/spartak/PycharmProjects/python_base/lesson_016/env', 'SNAP_ARCH': 'amd64',
            'SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID': '2099', 'XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP': 'ubuntu', 'GNOME_SETUP_DISPLAY': ':1',
            'SNAP_LIBRARY_PATH': '/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl:/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl32:/var/lib/snapd/void',
            'SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER': 'gnome-keyring', 'SHLVL': '0', 'LC_IDENTIFICATION': 'ru_RU.UTF-8',
            'LC_MONETARY': 'ru_RU.UTF-8', 'SNAP_NAME': 'pycharm-community', 'QT_IM_MODULE': 'ibus',
            'XDG_CONFIG_DIRS': '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg', 'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8',
            'SNAP_INSTANCE_NAME': 'pycharm-community', 'XDG_SESSION_TYPE': 'wayland',
            'SNAP_USER_DATA': '/home/spartak/snap/pycharm-community/256', 'PYDEVD_LOAD_VALUES_ASYNC': 'True',
            'DISPLAY': ':0', 'SNAP_REEXEC': '', 'WAYLAND_DISPLAY': 'wayland-0',
            'LIBRARY_ROOTS': '/home/spartak/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9:/home/spartak/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload:/home/spartak/PycharmProjects/python_base/lesson_016/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages:/home/spartak/.cache/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.2/python_stubs/-1475777083:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/python-skeletons:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stdlib:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/jwt:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/six:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/mock:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/nmap:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/annoy:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/attrs:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/polib:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/retry:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/docopt:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/enum34:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/orjson:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/pysftp:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/xxhash:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/chardet:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/futures:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/pyaudio:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/tzlocal:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/Markdown:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/Werkzeug:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/aiofiles:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/colorama:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/filelock:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/paramiko:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/pathlib2:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/requests:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/waitress:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/freezegun:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/ipaddress:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/pyRFC3339:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/typed-ast:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/Deprecated:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/cachetools:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/frozendict:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/pyfarmhash:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/JACK-Client:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/contextvars:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/atomicwrites:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/cryptography:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/DateTimeRange:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/click-spinner:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/pkg_resources:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/python-gflags:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/python-slugify:/snap/pycharm-community/256/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed/stubs/python-dateutil',
            'SNAP_VERSION': '2021.2.3', 'LC_NAME': 'ru_RU.UTF-8', 'XDG_SESSION_CLASS': 'user',
            '_': '/usr/bin/gnome-session', 'SNAP_DATA': '/var/snap/pycharm-community/256', 'PYTHONIOENCODING': 'UTF-8',
            'DESKTOP_SESSION': 'ubuntu', 'SNAP': '/snap/pycharm-community/256', 'USER': 'spartak',
            'SNAP_REAL_HOME': '/home/spartak', 'XDG_MENU_PREFIX': 'gnome-', 'GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID': '122719',
            'QT_ACCESSIBILITY': '1', 'PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE': '1', 'LC_NUMERIC': 'ru_RU.UTF-8',
            'GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT': 'stderr', 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK': '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh', 'PYTHONUNBUFFERED': '1',
            'GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE': 'ubuntu',
            'SNAP_CONTEXT': 'AoM6cqDJGx0xxWBUHLXWyVdhoNwTuHJsXSu2foumZWGYLCOaeHoL', 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR': '/run/user/1000',
            'SNAP_COOKIE': 'AoM6cqDJGx0xxWBUHLXWyVdhoNwTuHJsXSu2foumZWGYLCOaeHoL', 'HOME': '/home/spartak',
            'QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH': '/home/spartak/PycharmProjects/python_base/lesson_016/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins',
            'QT_QPA_FONTDIR': '/home/spartak/PycharmProjects/python_base/lesson_016/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/qt/fonts',
            'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/home/spartak/PycharmProjects/python_base/lesson_016/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/../../lib64:'})
```

Comment: are you sure it stops after `namedWindow`? Maybe it stops after `waitKey` and it waits until you press any key. maybe first you should use `print()` to see which lines of code are executed. Warning is not a error and it shouldn't stop code. But you may try to set environmetn variable `QT_QPA_PLATFORM` before run code or directly in code using `os.environ`

Comment: I did trial with print. Program stops on namedWindow. Screen there: https://wampi.ru/image/REcVkeq

Comment: maybe you shoudl try `os.environ["QT_QPA_PLATFORM"] = "wayland"` at start

Comment: I tried this. Put this into my code and received this: https://wampi.ru/image/RExRI84

Comment: I have no idea how to resolve it - I use Linux Mint based on Ubuntu 20.04 which still use `xorg` instead of `wayland`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I reverted back to Xorg from wayland and its working, no more warnings

Here are the steps:

1. Disabled Wayland by uncommenting `WaylandEnable=false` in the `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`
2. Add `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb` in `/etc/environment`
3. Check whether you are on Wayland or Xorg using:

   ```
   echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
   ```

Comment: I tried the steps. It still shows wayland for echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE.

Comment: same problem for me too. echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE returns wayland

Comment: it helps for me Follow these steps and restart the machine

Comment: Confirming that restarting has worked. The output you should expect is x11.

Answer (score 6):

The same `Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway` appears when drawing a plot with pandas and matplotlib on Wayland. If you don't want to deactivate Wayland and go back to X11, you have the alternative to save the figure to a pdf file.

Create some data and a plot

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({'x':range(0,30), 'y':range(10,40)})
df.set_index('x', inplace=True)
plot = df.plot(title='A nice line')

# Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
```

Save the figure to a pdf file as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35484726/2641825):

```
plot.get_figure().savefig('/tmp/output.pdf', format='pdf')
```

Or use [jupyter lab](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to display the plot in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem running matplotlib from python 3.10 with Debian 12.4 (gnome/wayland). I tried suppressing warnings and filtering logging in python to no effect. I didn't want to disable wayland, though I know that would fix the issue.

What worked for me in the python code:

```
os.environ["XDG_SESSION_TYPE"] = "xcb"
```

This line can be either before or after the matplotlib import statement. This only works without warnings if you have qtwayland5 installed first. And PyQt5 installed from pip.